# Request Entity Too Large error while uploading files of more than 128KB over SSL

Tags: ssl, https

We have a web portal setup on Java spring framework.

It is running on an Apache Tomcat app server. Portal is served through Apache web server connected to Tomcat through JK connector. Entire portal is HTTPS enabled using 443 port of apache. Apache version is: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) which is the latest stable version of Apache web server as of this posting.

Whenever we try to upload files more than 128KB into the portal, We are facing 413 error:

```
Request Entity Too Large The requested resource /teamleadchoachingtracking/doFileUpload does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

In the apache error log we get the following errors:

```
AH02018: request body exceeds maximum size (131072) for SSL buffer
AH02257: could not buffer message body to allow SSL renegotiation to proceed
```

We did a Google search and there were suggestions to put `SSLRenegBufferSize` as some high value like 10MB. Based on these suggestions, we had put the following entry in virtualhost section of httpd config file:

```
<Directory "/teamleadchoachingtracking/doFileUpload/">
SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
</Directory>
```

But still the error persists.

Also we have specified `SSLVerifyClient` none, but still renegotiation is happening.

This is a very inconsistent and frustrating error. Any help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the bug thread on Apache bugzilla's site? There are a few other workarounds discussed that might be of use to you. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39243

Comment: I did go through all that before posting here. Even after following those suggestions issue still persists. At the end of all these SSLRenegBufferSize param was the official fix from apache which we tried. That did not solve it.

Answer (score 19):

I managed to solve it by putting certain configuration in the Apache `httpd.conf` file. Here is the sample configuration:

```
<Location "/calibration">
  SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
</Location>
```

Earlier I was not giving correct configuration. The key is the *exact* URL location which is causing HTTP 413 error. In the location directive exact URL location needs to be given.

`SSLRenegBufferSize` is the param which specifies the max buffer size in bytes in case a renegotiation happened. I set it to 10 MB. Apache default is 128KB.

Comment: After running into simillar issue, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html says: by default a strict scheme is enabled where every per-directory reconfiguration of SSL parameters causes a full SSL renegotiation handshake, you can try using SSLOptions +OptRenegotiate, but SSLVerifyClient directive in .htaccess or per directory will always force renegotiation, which means setting SSLRenegBufferSize, at the end, we went with a different virtual host, which was serving the specific directory

Comment: Actually you can use `<Location "/">` or `<Location />` to apply the setting to whole server (or whole VirtualHost).

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs during an SSL renegotiation.  In addition to setting the renegotiate buffer size on Apache to a very high number you have a few other options:

- Configure your (virtual) host to use only a single authentication
  scheme to avoid renegotiation all together
- Use a client that supports HTTP 1.1 Expect Header

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281628/ssl-renegotiation-with-client-certificate-causes-server-buffer-overflow

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen on my ubuntu 14.04/apache 2.4 server, assuming you're using `.htaccess` apache configuration, the `SSLVerifyDepth` parameter also triggers the SSL Renegociation **even if the `SSLVerifyClient` is `none`**.
Using the `SSLVerifyDepth`  configuration line will also **bypass the `SSLRenegBufferSize` value** you may had set for this directory and all subdirs.

There is something about the difference between using the `SSLVerifyDepth` in the per-server context and in the per-directory context in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifydepth).
I thus assume this problematic comportment will be the same with `<directory>` config lines.
Once read attentively, the doc also states this parm will force the reneg...

**This solution did work for me :**

- put the `SSLVerifyDepth` in your main `ssl.conf` or in your virtual host conf, `SSLVerifyDepth 5` should fit a vast majority of major cert providers' cert chains.
- put the `SSLRenegBufferSize` with the required size in a `.htaccess` or in a `<directory>` per-directory configuration.