# Apache SSL / SSLVerifyClient and renegotiation buffer during upload

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request Entity Too Large error while uploading files of more than 128KB over SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/419723/request-entity-too-large-error-while-uploading-files-of-more-than-128kb-over-ssl)

We have Apache 2.16 web servers where authentication is made via X509 client certificates (they come from chips cards). Here is the Directory configuration :

```
<Directory /directory>
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 5
        SSLRequireSSL
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
</Directory>
```

The authentication run fine, but from times to times, when the user try to upload a file the upload fail, and we find this in the apache error log :

```
[Thu Dec 06 09:14:25 2012] [error] [client 80.82.235.94] Re-negotiation request failed
[Thu Dec 06 09:14:25 2012] [error] SSL Library Error: 336068931 error:14080143:SSL routines:SSL3_ACCEPT:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
[Thu Dec 06 09:14:25 2012] [error] [client 80.82.235.94] request body exceeds maximum size (131072) for SSL buffer
[Thu Dec 06 09:14:25 2012] [error] [client 80.82.235.94] could not buffer message body to allow SSL renegotiation to proceed
```

But even using the SSLRenegBufferSize directive the user still have the bug (it's pure random). The big problem is I can't even reproduce the bug. The http client (browser) may be the difference between me and the user, I only have Firefox 17 under Linux, and I am collecting information from the user.

The optional value for SSLVerifyClient is needed since it allow our software to handle when a user don't have his certificate, or when a certificate is expired. Otherwise the browser just show a technical error page, not suitable to our users.

Comment: you already tried the solutions of this link ? http://serverfault.com/questions/419723/request-entity-too-large-error-while-uploading-files-of-more-than-128kb-over-ssl

Comment: No, I have not found it, but I try it right now. Thanks.

Comment: Own3r, your tip is good and the situation get better. The problem still occurs, but we can retry the upload and it work. Thanks. It's a brain damage problem! I will flag your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs randomly because this happens only when renegotiation is needed, by the way this post should contain the answer to the question
[Request Entity Too Large error while uploading files of more than 128KB over SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/419723/request-entity-too-large-error-while-uploading-files-of-more-than-128kb-over-ssl)